# How to read rtf attached to the document to RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, rtf

I attached rtf document to my app, and I want its content to be display in RichTextBox, I know how to do that with rtf file from disk, but I can't access file in project.

Comment: clarify "attached rtf document to my app" you mean embedded in your project?

Answer (score 0):

If you added the rtf file as "Embedded Resource" in your project use GetManifestResourceStream etc functions on the executing assembly. Check out a sample here : http://lamahashim.blogspot.com/2009/06/c-reading-embedded-files-at-runtime.html